# QMessageBox::information should be application modal but is not

Tags: qt, networking, dialog, modal-dialog

In my application, I do some tests at startup, and in case something is wrong, a dialog box is displayed. If several ones are displayed, this is done sequentially, they are not stacked together at the same time. This is properly working application modality.

I also check for new version with a QNetworkManager connected to one of my main window slots. If a new version is available, it prompts the user with a dialog.

The problem is, the new version dialog is stacked above the system check dialog. This seems linked to the fact that it is triggered by a QNetworkManager signal

Here is what the `MainWindow::showEvent` overload does:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(checkSomeStuff()));

QNetworkAccessManager * networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(versionCheck(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), networkManager, SLOT(deleteLater()));
QString address = QString("http://www.mycompany.com/checkversions.dat");
networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(address));
```

The in `MainWindow::checkSomeStuff()`

```
if(!someStuff())
{
    int result = QMessageBox::information(this,
             "Stuff missing",
             "Stuff is missing. Are you sure you want to run the app?",
             QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

    if(result != QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        this->close();
    }
}
```

And in `MainWindow::versionCheck()`

```
QMessageBox mb(this);
mb.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
mb.setWindowTitle(tr("Download new version?"));
mb.setText(tr("Download new version?"));
mb.addButton(QMessageBox::Yes);
mb.addButton(QMessageBox::No);
mb.addButton(tr("Maybe later"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);
int button = mb.exec();
```

I'm using Qt 5.6.2

Comment: Sounds like you may have missed parenting the message box that isn't appearing as modal. Note that a code example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is much better than just a description of an issue.

Comment: No, the MainWindow is passed as the parent of every message box (thus this should not be the cause even if I had passed null parents : this is app modality, not window modality)

Comment: This is a large app. I know that reproducing in a MCVE would be great but it's not guaranteed to reproduce the issue easily. I'll try to do one as a last resort if nobody has got a clue

Comment: Can you show how you create your QMessageBox ? Have you tried with a null parent ? Maybe the modality is automatically changed to WindowModal when you specify a parent ?

Comment: **This is a large app...but it's not guaranteed to reproduce the issue easily.** - it sounds to me like you don't understand your own application. The act of creating the MCVE will assist your understanding and may help highlight the issue to you, before the need to add it to your question. As it stands, on its own, the textual description of the issue of modality is likely to only lead to guesses as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight : Not at all. I know my application very well, it's my life for 5 years. And I know that the issue could be long to reproduce in a MCVE since it could disappear by stripping the code in many ways. So as I'm looking to be as efficient as possible, I'd like to check if there may be a simple explanation before taking time isolating the issue in a MCVE. Which I will do if no good solution is found by another way.

Comment: The app is a large CGI software, initializes a lot of stuff at startup, checks things over the network, load some dlls, decides to start in command line mode or GUI mode depending on command line, postpones checks, with timers, etc...